# gwt - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/js/JsKeywords

Tags: gwt

I am trying to compile gwt module. This error is generated , env has gwt-log-3.1.8 and gwtsdk-2.4.0. Any idea why this is happening. It used work earlier in different project.

Error :

[java] Loading inherited module 'com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-OFF'
     [java]    Loading inherited module 'com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-impl'
     [java]       [ERROR] Line 87: Unexpected exception while processing element 'property-provider'
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/dev/js/JsKeywords
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsScope.maybeMangleKeyword(JsScope.java:56)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.ast.JsScope.declareName(JsScope.java:75)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParser.mapVar(JsParser.java:1229)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParser.map(JsParser.java:324)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParser.mapStatement(JsParser.java:1026)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParser.mapStatements(JsParser.java:1046)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParser.mapBlock(JsParser.java:442)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParser.mapFunction(JsParser.java:718)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.js.JsParser.map(JsParser.java:296)

Answer (score 0):

JsKeywords class is part of gwt-dev.jar. Make sure that this jar is in classpath.

Comment: "Loading inherited module" necessarily comes from some class in `gwt-dev`, so you can be sure it's in the classpath. This is weird; maybe gwt-dev is corrupted?